# UNION ALL statement not allowing additional column to be inserted on last table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I got this error message:

```
The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns
```

This is my full code:

```
<?php
$columns = [];
$stmt = $conn->prepare("
    SELECT valueA AS valueA FROM tableA
    UNION ALL
    SELECT valueB AS valueB FROM tableB
    UNION ALL
    SELECT valueC AS valueC, valueCA AS valueCA FROM tableC;
  ");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
  $points[] = $row;
}
$stmt->close();

foreach($columns as $column):
    if ($column->valueA):
        echo $column->valueA;
    elseif ($column->valueB):
        echo $column->valueB;
    elseif ($column->valueC):
        echo $column->valueC;
        echo $column->valueCA;
    endif;
endforeach; ?>
```

What I want to do is include `valueCA` on my last table `tableC`, but the error message states that I cannot do that. How would I fix my code to get this to work? Thank you

Comment: You can't have different number of columns in a single SQL result (which is a table). You can also not have different column names for the same column.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel So LukaszSzozda gave a solution that I add `NULL AS valueCA` to the first two `select statements` using the same column names - is this the solution you are referring to? Because that answer doesn't seem to work?

Comment: The answer does work, but isn't complete. As I wrote, you can't have four colums names in a result with two columns. There won't be `$column->valueB` or `$column->valueC` - Only `$column->valueA` and `$column->valueCA`. The column names are determined by the first part of the UNION statement.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel So how would I get this to work to include `$column->valueB` and `$column->valueC`? The reason I said it doesn't work is because I tried his code, and it still does not display the value for `$column->valueCA`?

Comment: Something like `if ($column->valueA):  echo $column->valueA; if ($column->valueCA):  echo $column->valueCA;`

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Ah I see now, it works. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide value like `NULL`:

```
SELECT valueA AS valueA, NULL AS valueCA FROM tableA
UNION ALL
SELECT valueB AS valueB, NULL AS valueCA FROM tableB
UNION ALL
SELECT valueC AS valueC, valueCA AS valueCA FROM tableC
```

Comment: This cleared the error message, but it's still not echoing out `valueCA` from the database?

Comment: Ok works now, so I needed to fix my if statement as suggested by Paul. Thanks greatly for the simple explanation and providing me with the solution!